# events in a file system watcher

Tags: c#

when i use a  file system watcher changed event  for a notepad it occurs once,but the event occurs twice for a word pad,please give me the reason.i launch using explorer

A bit Briefly,
                I have a file named "xxx.log" it contains some strings,i wrote a filesystemwatcher which will watch this file for size(notifyfilter - size) changed.whenever
i opened the file with notepad the changedevent occurs once,whenevr i do it with wordpad
the event occurs twice what is the reason. i open files using explorer.exe.

how to handle this problem.i need the event once only,is there any way

Comment: Yes - this is a bit brief - e.g. explain how you launch word and notepad - via the expplorer - is it the same via the Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that notepad has no lock/backup file handling. Thus it writes only once to the file - Word and Wordpad work with some temporary files for backup and locking purposes and for that reason they might write twice.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand this is to use process monitor from sysinternals. This will show you exactly what is going on.